# TSQL Stored Procedure Syntax Error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I tried to write a stored procedure but although the single parts seems correct when I put all together I get (3) Syntax Errors:

> near keyword 'CASE'
>
> near keyword 'ELSE'
>
> near keyword 'FROM'

** ADDED:
The purpose of the query is to calculate the current trackingnumber adding 1 to latest Seed taking the number from a given batch, and if last number of the current batch is reached.... copy new batch into current batch
**

here is the stored procedure: if somebody can give a hints:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spGetTrackingNumber
(
  @SUID         nvarchar (60),
  @CarrierID    nvarchar (20)
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @S      nvarchar(max)='',
        @P      nvarchar(max)='',
        @OUT    nvarchar(max)=''

SELECT @S= 'CASE WHEN (s.LastSeed+1=s.FinalSeed )
            THEN    
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE t SET 
                        LastSeed=NewInitialSeed, 
                        FinalSeed=NewFinalSeed, 
                        NewInitialSeed=NULL, 
                        NewFinalSeed=NULL 
                    OUTPUT 
                        deleted.LastSeed+1 AS CurrentSeed, 
                        deleted.Prefix, 
                        deleted.PostFix, 
                        deleted.CarrierName, 
                        deleted.TrackingUrl
                        (FinalSeed - inserted.LastSeed) AS RemainingSeeds
                    FROM TrackingSeed   t
                    JOIN Users          u   ON  t.UID=u.UID
                    JOIN SubUsers       su  ON  su.UID=u.UID
                    WHERE 
                        su.SUID=@_SUID 
                    AND t.CarrierCode=@_CarrierID 
                END
            ELSE 
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE t SET 
                        LastSeed=LastSeed+1 
                    OUTPUT 
                        inserted.LastSeed+1 AS CurrentSeed, 
                        inserted.Prefix, Inserted.PostFix, 
                        inserted.CarrierName, 
                        inserted.TrackingUrl, 
                        (FinalSeed - inserted.LastSeed) AS RemainingSeeds
                    FROM TrackingSeed t
                    JOIN Users u ON t.UID=u.UID
                    JOIN SubUsers su ON su.UID=u.UID
                    WHERE 
                        su.SUID=@_SUID 
                    AND t.CarrierCode=@_CarrierID 
                END
            END  
        FROM TrackingSeed       s 
            JOIN Users          u   ON  s.UID=u.UID 
            JOIN SubUsers       su  ON  u.UID=su.UID 
            WHERE 
                s.CarrierCode=@_CarrierID 
            AND su.SUID=@_SUID'

            PRINT @S                    


SET @P= '@_SUID         nvarchar(60),
         @_CarrierID    nvarchar(20),
         @_OUT          nvarchar(max) OUTPUT'

EXEC sp_executesql @S, @P, @SUID, @CarrierID,@OUT OUTPUT
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

thanks!

Comment: **CASE is not for [Control-of-Flow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174290.aspx)**. Also you should describe what is your query  doing and why do you reinvent `IDENTITY/SEQUENCE`

Comment: Hi! I tried also using `IF ELSE` but still **syntax error near keyword 'FROM'**

Comment: Why are you even using *dynamic SQL* ? Absolutely not needed - just use the proper SQL statements inside the stored procedure - don't make it more complicated than necessary!

Comment: @lad2025
"Answering to a question with another question" :THIS is really not useful, since you are not bound to answer, if you got up on the wrong side of the bed.. you could simply do a walk.

Comment: 1) Probably Dynamic-SQL is not necessary at all 2) You cannot use `CASE` as control flow 3) You can use `IF ELSE` 4)  `LastSeed=LastSeed+1` sounds like very poor design 5) Your code is just one syntax error 6) [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 7) If you need tech support hire consultant. By the way I am in great mood today :)

Comment: @marc_s

Hi Marc, actually I'm using always the same schema with input, tests and output, and it is easier for me to modify the same schema instead of create new schemas.. but will try to work as suggested.
Thanks

Comment: @Joe: just **don't overuse** dynamic SQL - use it *sparingly* - when you really need it. Don't just use it all the time - bad idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why you even resort to *dynamic SQL* - there's absolutely no need for that!

I don't totally understand where you get your values from that you're using in the `CASE` in your sample code - I'm just **guessing** here - you might need to adapt this to your actual situation.

But in the end, I think code something like this should do what you're asking for:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spGetTrackingNumber
(
  @SUID      nvarchar(60),
  @CarrierID nvarchar(20)
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- declare variables used to make your decision which UPDATE to execute
    DECLARE @LastSeed INT, @FinalSeed INT;

    -- fetch those variables - here I'm just *GUESSING* - adapt to your needs if I'm wrong
    SELECT
        @LastSeed = s.LastSeed,
        @FinalSeed = s.FinalSeed
    FROM 
        dbo.TrackingSeed s 
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.Users u ON s.UID = u.UID 
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.SubUsers su ON u.UID = su.UID 
    WHERE 
        s.CarrierCode = @_CarrierID 
        AND su.SUID = @_SUID

    -- depending on the your values - run the one or the other UPDATE statement
    IF (@LastSeed + 1 = @FinalSeed)
        UPDATE t 
        SET 
           LastSeed = NewInitialSeed, 
           FinalSeed = NewFinalSeed, 
           NewInitialSeed = NULL, 
           NewFinalSeed = NULL 
       OUTPUT 
           deleted.LastSeed + 1 AS CurrentSeed, deleted.Prefix, deleted.PostFix, deleted.CarrierName, 
           deleted.TrackingUrl, (FinalSeed - inserted.LastSeed) AS RemainingSeeds
       FROM 
           dbo.TrackingSeed t
       INNER JOIN 
           dbo.Users u ON t.UID = u.UID
       INNER JOIN 
           dbo.SubUsers su ON su.UID = u.UID
       WHERE 
           su.SUID = @_SUID 
           AND t.CarrierCode = @_CarrierID 
    ELSE                
        UPDATE t 
        SET LastSeed = LastSeed + 1 
        OUTPUT 
            inserted.LastSeed + 1 AS CurrentSeed, inserted.Prefix, Inserted.PostFix, 
            inserted.CarrierName, inserted.TrackingUrl, (FinalSeed - inserted.LastSeed) AS RemainingSeeds
       FROM 
           dbo.TrackingSeed t
       INNER JOIN 
           dbo.Users u ON t.UID = u.UID
       INNER JOIN 
           dbo.SubUsers su ON su.UID = u.UID
       WHERE 
           su.SUID = @_SUID 
           AND t.CarrierCode = @_CarrierID
```

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for considerations and also for solution.. but like it is it is not working:
I think the `THEN` just after the `IF` statement has to be removed, but also with that  still remains a couple of error: 
LastSeed and FinalSeed are not valid Column Name: I can guess that's because  the `IF` statement has not a `WHERE` part.. but.. how have to place it? not in the bottom and neither before update :-(.. will test further
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Joe: sorry, some typos (typing from memory without possibility of checking this) - updated my response

Comment: yes.. all OK..except a mispelled word: `dob` instead of `dbo`: I tried to edit your answer but minimum amend is 6 charater while I should change only 2, but it is all OK

Comment: your answer is OK as well as the one's of Stefan..
since he has fewer points than you is it OK if I accept his answer and not yours?

Comment: @joe: that is entirely your decision :-)

Answer (score 3):

First you miss SELECT from the beginning of query
then you have missing coma after "deleted.TrackingUrl",
you can't use UPDATE in CASE WHEN THEN ( or use UDF )
and UPDATE OUTPUT need INTO 
and like marc_c say "Why are you even using dynamic SQL"

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @LastSeed INT
   DECLARE @FinalSeed INT
   SELECT TOP 1 
    @LastSeed = ISNULL(s.LastSeed,0)   ,
    @FinalSeed = ISNULL(s.FinalSeed,0)
    FROM TrackingSeed       s 
        JOIN Users          u   ON  s.UID=u.UID 
        JOIN SubUsers       su  ON  u.UID=su.UID 
        WHERE 
        s.CarrierCode=@_CarrierID 
        AND 
        su.SUID=@_SUID


    IF  @LastSeed+1=@FinalSeed
    BEGIN
            UPDATE t SET 
                    LastSeed=NewInitialSeed, 
                    FinalSeed=NewFinalSeed, 
                    NewInitialSeed=NULL, 
                    NewFinalSeed=NULL 
                OUTPUT 
                    deleted.LastSeed+1 AS CurrentSeed, 
                    deleted.Prefix, 
                    deleted.PostFix, 
                    deleted.CarrierName, 
                    deleted.TrackingUrl,
                    (FinalSeed - inserted.LastSeed) AS RemainingSeeds INTO TABLENAMEFOROUTPUT
                FROM TrackingSeed   t
                JOIN Users          u   ON  t.UID=u.UID
                JOIN SubUsers       su  ON  su.UID=u.UID
                WHERE 
                    su.SUID=@_SUID 
                AND t.CarrierCode=@_CarrierID 
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
                UPDATE t SET 
                    LastSeed=LastSeed+1 
                OUTPUT 
                    inserted.LastSeed+1 AS CurrentSeed, 
                    inserted.Prefix, Inserted.PostFix, 
                    inserted.CarrierName, 
                    inserted.TrackingUrl, 
                    (FinalSeed - inserted.LastSeed) AS RemainingSeeds INTO TABLENAMEFOROUTPUT
                FROM TrackingSeed t
                JOIN Users u ON t.UID=u.UID
                JOIN SubUsers su ON su.UID=u.UID
                WHERE 
                    su.SUID=@_SUID 
                AND t.CarrierCode=@_CarrierID 
    END
```

Comment: Yess Stefan.. seems working well.. will make some further tests..
Thanks a Lot